# Ящик спец.назначения, прикрывающий трубы

Tags: грамотная-речь

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как называется ящик и какое имеет назначение?

Comment: Спец.назначение — два слова.

Answer (score 1):

Шкаф пожарный квартирный. Или просто *пожарный шкаф*.